# FBSDK - sharerDidCancel is not getting called in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented FB Sdk in my app for sharing. I works fine for sharing but

`-(void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer` only this method is not getting called when I cancelled to post.

it calling `-(void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results` with **Empty results dictionary when Cancel pressed or Successfully posted**

**my code to open share dialog is as follow:**
`[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];`

**this is a very big problem by FB**

**How can I differentiate Posted vs Cancelled?**

**Help me to solve this**

Comment: i am facing an issue regarding FBSDK .. Can you tell me how to work with FBSDK for login nd all

Comment: are you sure you are setting the delegate  **[self.shareCodeDialog setDelegate:self]**  like that

Comment: @NitinGohel,Thanks a lot for your answer  I am calling share dialog as `[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];`

Comment: @NitinGohel, it is also not working in FB iOS Sdk 4.4.0 share kit example given by Facebook itself!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to differentiate between posted and cancelled?

Comment: @WizKid, I want to show message when comes backs to app

Comment: But the dialog will tell the user that

Comment: @WizKid still I want to differentiate this things. & then what is the use of Cancel method?

Comment: I think it is a legacy thing that wasn't removed because it would break apps